# Meteor.js event on client data redrawn/update

Tags: javascript, meteor, datatables

Is there a way to know on the client side when the data has been re-rendered?

I am using [aldeed:tabular](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/tabular) package and the problem I'm having is that when the data changes, I loose my selected highlighted row because the table is completely redrawn.

So, I need to catch this re-rendering event in order to re-highlight my selected row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your data table options, add a callback function for the `drawCallback` property, [documented here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)

Like so:

```
TabularTables.MyTable = new Tabular.Table({
  // other DT properties...
  drawCallback: function( settings ) {
    // do your magic here
  }
});
```